# Polynomials in the complex ring of 2 variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, complex-geometry

Given $I = \left<x^2+y^2-1, x^2-y+1, xy-1\right>$ show that this generates $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

I have tried pages and pages of writing a linear combination of these such that the combination is equal to 1 to show that the ideal contains 1 and is thus the whole ring.  I have also tried looking at this geometrically and trying to show that they have no zeroes in common. Then applying the hilbert nullstellensatz.  is this the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

You want tot show that $\Bbb C[x,y]/I$ is the trivial ring. You can start out dividing out by one of the polynomials that involves $y$ in a simple way (both the second and last polynomial are candidates). Taking $x^2-y+1$ for this, which says that in the quotient $y=x^2+1$, one gets an isomorphism
$$
  \Bbb C[x,y]/I\cong\Bbb C[x]/\left<x^2+(x^2+1)^2-1,x(x^2+1)-1\right>
 =\Bbb C[x]/\left<x^4+3x^2,x^3+x-1\right>.
$$
Now it is not hard to calculate that the remaining two polynomials are relatively prime in $\Bbb C[x]$, so that the quotient is trivial.

I might add that, if my extended Euclidean algorithm calculations are correct, a Bezout relation for those to polynomials is given by
$$
  52=(20x^2+16x+12)(x^4+3x^2)+(-20x^3-16x^2-52x-52)(x^3+x-1),
$$
which (almost) shows how hairy these computations get (almost, because the actual computations work with rational coefficients); in your original setting you would still need to find which multiple of $x^2-y+1$ enters into the mix. So it is not really surprising that you did not manage to write $1$ explicitly as a combination of the given polynomials.